# Disable the display of "terminated xxx" info of bash

Tags: bash, signals

For example, when I kill a background process, then bash weil display 
`terminated xxx`, How to disable this info?

```
$ ping g.cn >/dev/null &
[1] 25123
$ pkill ping
[1]  + 25123 terminated  ping g.cn > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the command in a subshell:

```
( ping g.cn >/dev/null & )
```

instead of

```
ping g.cn >/dev/null &
```

Doing so would not show the process terminated message upon killing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can `disown` the background job:

```
$ ping g.cn > /dev/null &
[1] 25123
$ disown %1
$ kill 25123
$ ps ax | grep '[2]5123'
$
```

This will detach the process from the running shell.  Note that this will also prevent you from getting the job back to foreground.